# How to obtain SQL equal fields in a group of records?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am programming a website and have a question what is the best way to implement something. It can do this in PHP, but want to know if there is a way to do this in SQL.

This is my table:

### Servidores

```
idServidor      int(11)
servidor        varchar(255)
idestado        int(11)
ip              varchar(15)
idPlataforma    int(11)
firewall        tinyint(1)
comentario      varchar(255)

1       mafalda         1       10.10.1.150     1       1       NA
2       mafaldavm       1       10.10.1.150     1       1       NA
3       proxy           1       10.4.4.25       2       0       NA
4       proxy-old       2       10.4.4.21       2       0       NA
5       tintoreto       1       10.4.4.20       4       1       NA
```

So, now I want to get from a group of records, just fields thar are equals. If there is one field in the group that is different, that field should return null or empty.
Only for the fields idestado, ip, idplataforma and firewall.

Example, if want to get equals fields for idServidor in (1,2,3), the query shuld return:

```
idestado,ip,idplataforma,firewall
1,null,null,null
```

For group idServidor in (1,3,5):

```
idestado,ip,idplataforma,firewall
1,null,null,1
```

For group idServidor in (1,2):

```
idestado,ip,idplataforma,firewall
1,10.10.1.150,1,1
```

I'm trying with this query, but just work for one field.

```
SELECT idestado 
FROM servidores 
WHERE idServidor IN (1,2,3) 
GROUP BY idestado HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You write your example but dont explain the logic behind.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do that, I don't know if it is the best but it work:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT idEstado FROM servidores 
        WHERE idservidor IN (1, 2, 3) 
        GROUP BY idestado HAVING COUNT(*)=3) AS idEstado,
    (SELECT ip FROM servidores 
        WHERE idservidor IN ( 1, 2, 3)
        GROUP BY ip HAVING COUNT(*)=3) AS ip,
    (SELECT idPlataforma FROM servidores 
        WHERE idservidor IN (1, 2, 3) 
        GROUP BY idPlataforma HAVING COUNT(*)=3) AS idPlataforma,
    (SELECT firewall FROM servidores
        WHERE idservidor IN (1, 2, 3)
        GROUP BY firewall HAVING COUNT(*) =3) AS firewall
FROM dual
```

Comment: This query isn't easily extendable.  You would have to change a lot of code if you ever add a new column, or want to change the servers that you're checking.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how many rows you are comparing, if the values in the column are all the same, then the MIN and MAX of that column would be identical.  If there's at least one row with a different value in that column, then the MIN and MAX would be different.  With that in mind, here is the query:

```
select s.idestado,
case when MIN(s.ip) = MAX(s.ip) then MIN(s.ip) else null end ip,
case when MIN(s.idPlataforma) = MAX(s.idPlataforma) then MIN(s.idPlataforma) else null end idPlataforma,
case when MIN(s.firewall) = MAX(s.firewall) then MIN(s.firewall) else null end firewall
from Servidores s
where s.idServidor in (1,2,5)
group by idestado
```